# html5 file upload progress not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom-events

I wanted to show the progress of a file upload using
the the progress event bound to a `FileReader`,
however while it works in Chrome it does not work correctly in FireFox.

```
reader.onprogress=function(e){
if (e.lengthComputable==true) {
console.log("e.loaded: "+e.loaded);
console.log("e.total: "+e.total);
  var percentage = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);

   console.log("percentage: "+percentage);
  status.innerHTML = 'Loaded : '+percentage+'%';
}
```

The Chrome output for a file used as example is:

> e.total     e.loaded  e.lengthComputable
> 3763448  3763448 true

but for Firefox is:

> e.total      e.loaded  e.lengthComputable
> 3763448  786432       true

Does anyone one know why the progress is not being updated in Firefox?

The file is completely uploaded and is usable.
The problem is when showing the uploading progress.

Comment: Provide a full, reproducible example please. Also you say "file upload", but then talk about `FileReader`... Sounds more like `XMLHttpRequest.upload.onprogress`

Comment: well am using the file api to upload a file then i use 'readAsArrayBuffer' to start working with the file. am not using XHR